# Having troubles getting my rails form to work

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, frontend, simple-form-for

I've been trying for hours to get my rails form to work but I can't. The error that it keeps throwing says:

ArgumentError at /
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

and the line of code where it says this error occurs is at the f.input line. Any ideas?

```
.select-width
 = f.label :country 
 = f.input :country, :select, :as => :fancy_select, collection: ['South Africa', 'Nigeria', 'Zimbabwe', 'Mali', 'Namibia'], hint: 'Lorem ipsum hint'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `simple_form`, `input` requires only two parameters.

1. for field name
2. hash of options (This parameter is optional)

So, you can use following code. It will work fine.

```
.select-width
  = f.label :country
  = f.input :country, as: :fancy_select, collection: ['South Africa', 'Nigeria', 'Zimbabwe', 'Mali', 'Namibia'], hint: 'Lorem ipsum hint'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using `simple_form`:

I guess it will work:

```
= f.input :country, collection: ['South Africa', 'Nigeria', 'Zimbabwe', 'Mali', 'Namibia'], as: :fancy_select
```

You can check the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) how they define `select` tag.